# Perl script to parse XML using XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to parse the following XML. The problem is I get nothing in the output:

XML file:

```
<response>
  <response-name>SendUnitaryResponse</response-name>
    <params>
        <request-status>OK</request-status>
        <unitary-request-id>B4004A3E</unitary-request-id>
    </params>
</response>
```

Script:

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $access = XMLin('C:\Users\s.baccar\Desktop\access.log');
print $access->{response}->{response-name};
```

Answer (score 3):

As Sobrique points out, XML::Simple isn't that simple.  In this case, it removes the root element (`<response>`), which is why your print statement fails.  You can either change your print:

```
print $access->{response-name};
```

...or tell XML::Simple to keep the root element:

```
my $access = XMLin('C:/Users/s.baccar/Desktop/access.log', KeepRoot => 1);
```

...or best of all, use a different module.

Answer (score 1):

`XML::Simple` - isn't. It's for simple XML.

In it's documentation it says:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

Instead, I like [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) (other options exist):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

my $xml = q{<response>
  <response-name>SendUnitaryResponse</response-name>
    <params>
        <request-status>OK</request-status>
        <unitary-request-id>B4004A3E</unitary-request-id>
    </params>
</response>};

my $twig_parser = XML::Twig -> new -> parse ( $xml );
#in XML::Twig - root is the 'top' node, e.g. <response> in this case. 
print $twig_parser -> root -> first_child_text('response-name');
```

This also works if you give it a filename:

```
my $twig_parser = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'C:\Users\myuser\Documents\test.xml' );
print $twig_parser -> root -> first_child_text('response-name');
```

Comment: I test your code normolly i got OK in output but i got nothing

Comment: I did test and run the code I gave. It works with the sample input, printing "SendUnitaryResponse"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what other people have said, please `use strict;` ( and `use warnings;` )

If I add those to your script, I get:

```
Bareword "response" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at x.pl line 8.
Bareword "name" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at x.pl line 8.
```

( Note that line 8 is `print $access->{response}->{response-name};` )

That line is effectively being turned into `print $access->{response}->{0};`

You need to use `'response-name'`.